# Hidden Column in Sharepoint shows up in excel down

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list where I hide a column on the list view but when I download the list it shows up in the excel download. I checked the modified view setting and the hidden column is checked off. How can I not show it  in excel download?

Thank!

Comment: Are you using Modern or Classic SharePoint UX?  Also, is this field present in any of the forms used to input data?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods for your reference：

**SolutionA:**

1.In my test, I hide "Brand" and "Site" column in the list

[image]

[image]

2.Click on **Export** >> **Export to Excel**

[image]

3.Open the query.iqy file, you cannot see "Brand" and "Site" column in this excel file

[image]

**SolutionB:**

1.Please run the below script as an admin to export items to excel. Note that the value of **$SelectedFields** should be the internal name of the column

[image]

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName = "list name"
$SelectedFields = @("ID","Sentiment","Email", "CompletionDate")
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListData.csv"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Get List items from the list
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields $SelectedFields -PageSize 500
 
#Iterate through each item and extract data
$ListDataColl = @()
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
    $ListData = New-Object PSObject
    #Get the Field Values of the item as text
    $ListItem  = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property FieldValuesAsText
    ForEach($Field in $SelectedFields)
    {
        $ListData | Add-Member Noteproperty $Field $ListItem[$Field]
    } 
    $ListDataColl += $ListData 
}
#Export data to CSV
$ListDataColl
$ListDataColl | Export-CSV $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

2.Open the CSV file, you only see the columns value that you selected

[image]

============================ **Updated Answer** ======================

**Please run the below script as an admin:**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
     
#Get the Web 
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://SiteURL" 
     
#Get the Target List 
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"] 
     
#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects 
$ListItemCollection = @() 
     
#Get All List items by specifying fields 
$list.Items | foreach { 
$ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
#Specify fields (Add the columns that you want to display) 
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"] 
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Text" -value $_["Text"] 
$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Column1" -value $_["Column1"] 
     
#Add the object with property to an Array 
$ListItemCollection += $ExportItem 
} 

#Export the result Array to CSV file 
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "C:\ListData.csv" -NoTypeInformation                        
     
#Dispose the web Object 
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you but i am using sharepoint 2003. The solutionA does not look same as mine.  SolutionB is not possible since I don't know how run a script as an admin. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Hi Nina. Sorry, because your problem tag is SharePoint-Online, so I provide solutions in SharePoint Online. Don’t worry, I will re-provide my solution.

Comment: Hi Nina. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry but non of this will work for me. I am new to SharePoint site. Also I do not have Poweshell. Is there a script I can use using Sharepoint Developer?